# I submitted my resume with a minor mistake, should I resend it?

Tags: resume, employer-relations

In one of my bullets for leadership experience, I state:

`-Organizing electronics team schedule, meetings, deadlines and other criteria`

I think the "other criteria" part doesn't make sense, Is this glaring enough for an engineering firm to notice?

If so, is it worth resending?

Comment: If you have a small wording mistake in something you send out, be confident in your error until they call you on it.  Then "notice" it and correct it soon as you can.

Comment: What do you mean by "notice it and correct" are you talking about during an interview or?

Comment: It's important to consider who will be reading this. One screen will be HR who will look for keywords and trash or keep based on that alone. The other screen will be the hiring manager who can find a good engineer in spite of a minor ambiguity on a resume.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You've already sent it out. Sending out another one in such a short time is likely to be seen as spamming and could do more damage to your image and how the company perceives you than two unnecessary words on your resume. The only time you would really send out another resume to the same firm is if your first resume was the wrong format or did not contain the relevant information pertaining to that firm's vacant position.

Such a small matter like those two words are unlikely to make a big difference. I recommend just not worrying about it and keep trekking forward in your job search.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely, definitely correct your resume to make sure an end comes to that phrase.

Do send it to new potential employers.

Don't bother resending to anyone just for that change.  90% won't notice it.  99% won't care.  The one percent who *do* care you do not want to work for.

Answer (score 0):

It's good you recognize it as a somewhat weak resume statement about leadership. As one who reads a lot of resumes, fuzzy statements like that can lower my opinion of the candidate, especially if they have some years of experience under their belt. You should revise your resume and send it again to the company(s) with the explanation that you want them to have the most recent update to your resume (don't highlight what you changed).

But remember, you have no control over where your resumes get sent, and when, so be prepared for that phrase to show up. If it does, and they ask you about it, be prepared with a response of what "other criteria" was intended to imply. A good response will erase any doubts they may have about that phrase and what it might have implied.

Comment: If one awkward bullet point on your resume makes the difference between your being invited for an interview or not, you are already considered a pretty borderline candidate. I don't see any likely scenario where re-sending your resume just to tweak phrasing (as opposed to correcting a statement of fact) would be the difference between getting the interview or not, and once you're in the interview, the resume is just so much paper and ink.

Comment: Note that I didn't say it would kill the chance of the interview, only that it would lower my opinion of the person. Maybe I'm too strict, but if working at our company is important to you, I would expect your primary marketing piece to be done well. It's not a killer to send a new document and tell me that it's the most up-to-date version of it. Obviously most folks think it's not a big deal. I'm just different, I suppose.

Comment: I kinda agree with this in that if I were to receive an updated cv I'd look at it. However, by the time you resent the cv the chances are we've either invited you for an interview or not. Changing a couple of words isn't going to make any difference, at all. CVs are unrepresentative of actual experience anyway and broad swathes are more important.